# What's the meaning of "vertical" in a software project description?

Tags: meaning, american-english, software

I'm a programmer from Brazil and have here a software project to estimate. In the description I found these sentences:

> ...to provide the use cases for the **vertical** they might be interested.
>
> ...that would be suitable for that particular user and **vertical**.
>
> ...and the selected **vertical**.

I really don't get it. Does someone know the meaning of *vertical* in these cases?

Comment: Related at our [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) site: *[Meaning of 'retail vertical'](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15224)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a shortened form of "vertical market." From Wikipedia: [Vertical market](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_market).

Here's a bit that's particularly relevant to your question:

> Vertical market software is software aimed at addressing the needs of
>   any given business within a discernible vertical market. An example
>   could be software that manages services in hotels - amenities
>   solutions.